# Приведение double к float в C++

Tags: c++

Пусть переменная типа `double` приводится к переменной типа `float`.
Если переменная `double` хранит значение `NaN`, то оно преобразуется в `NaN`.
Если переменная `double` хранит значение `Inf`, то оно преобразуется в `Inf`.
Если переменная `double` хранит значение `-1e+50`, то оно преобразуется в `-Inf`.

Такое поведение гарантируется стандартом C++, или *IEEE 754*? Или это *implementation-defined behavior*, или это вообще undefined behaviour и рассчитывать на то, что `-1e+50` преобразуется в `-Inf` вообще говоря не стоит?

Comment: У Вас есть код где Вы "это" пытаетесь реализовать?

Comment: Нет. Однако, знать, что может произойти при приведении типов в некоторых ситуациях хотелось бы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>Строго говоря, стандарт не определяет размерности `float` и `double`, но в своём ответе я буду считать, что они разной размерности и представляют собой 32-х и 64-х разрядные типы данных соответственно.</sub>

Т.к. `float` может вмещать в себя числа от [±1.18×10^(−38) до ±3.4×10^38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), а Вы пытаетесь вместить в переменную `float`, переменную типа `double`, значение которой не может быть представлено во `float` в точности, Вы получаете `-inf`.  <strike>Вы получаете неопределённое поведение. Поэтому надеяться на `-inf` не стоит.</strike>

Первоначальный мой ответ, утверждающий, что получится неопределённое поведение, является неверным. Неопределённое поведение получается, если мы пытаемся поместить во `float` такое число, которое не может быть в нём представлено. Вот как это описано в стандарте:

Стандарт C++14 **[conv.double]**

> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly
>   represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is
>   that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion is an
>   implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Но это всё касается абстрактной реализации, а у нас она вполне конкретная (и в этом крылась моя ошибка — я примерил конкретную реализацию к абстрактному описанию и сделал ошибочный вывод). Раз уж я сделал предположение о диапазоне допустимых значений `float`, я взял конкретную реализацию — IEEE 754. А раз я взял эту реализацию, то и отталкиваться нужно от неё, а не от абстракции.

Согласно IEEE 754 бесконечность является частью типа, а следовательно его максимальные и минимальные значения не являются его ограничителями. Просто всё, что лежит вне допустимого диапазона приводится к нужному значению согласно правилам округления. Так вот, согласно этому правилу, если пытаться представить `-1e+50` во `float`, то получится `-INF` — это нормальное значение `float` и оно гарантировано при `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` равным `true`*.  Т.е. мы имеем эту ситуацию из стандарта: *«the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values»*.

Если же вышеозначенная константа равна `false`, то ответ на вопрос может быть другим, но рассмотрен он тоже должен быть в рамках конкретной реализации, т.к. у нас есть конкретная цифра в вопросе, которую мы не можем рассматривать без конкретики со стороны реализации.

Подводя итог: является ли подобное поведение, неопределённым поведением, зависит ли оно от реализации — всё это зависит от представление типов с плавающей точкой и не может быть рассмотрено вне оного.

<sub>* Я не нашёл текста самого документа, но многие документы, ссылающиеся на оный, утверждают это.</sub>

---

В языке C это, кстати, указано более явно: если среда поддерживает бесконечность, то результат определён и с примером из вопроса даст гарантировано `-inf`. Это описано в стандарте C11 **[5.2.4.2.2/p5]**

> The minimum range of representable values for a floating type is the
>   most negative finite floating-point number representable in that type
>   through the most positive finite floating point number representable in
>   that type. In addition, if negative infinity is representable in a
>   type, the range of that type is extended to all negative real numbers;
>   likewise, if positive infinity is representable in a type, the range
>   of that type is extended to all positive real numbers.

Comment: А как насчёт NaN и Inf?

Comment: @wololo, к сожалению, у меня нет чёткого ответа на этот вопрос. Согласно моему пониманию, +-INF и NaN принадлежат к той части, которая описана «can be exactly represented in the destination type», т.е. эти значения могут быть в равной степени представлены в обоих типах. Я не нашёл ни явного подтверждения своего понимания, ни его опровержения.

Comment: @ixSci, как `NaN` может быть *exactly represented*, если его мантисса может содержать произвольное значение, определяемое пользователем? (главное, чтобы ненулевое, иначе вместо NaN получаем бесконечность) При преобразовании часть битов этого значения придётся отбрасывать.

Comment: @Arhad, я не считаю, что битовый паттерн в этом описании имеет значение. NaN может быть представлен как в числах с одинарной точностью, так и в числах с двойной. Т.е. после конвертации NaN остаётся NaN'ом, не получается какое-то другое значение. То, что битовый баттерн может отличаться, на мой взгляд, не противоречит цитате из стандарта.

Comment: @wololo, я переписал ответ на диаметрально противоположный.

Comment: Ещё можно добавить, что эти самые правила округления не являются  строго зафиксированными и могут быть изменены с помощью манипуляций над управляющим словом FPU. Например, в Visual Studio для этого есть функции, такие как `_controlfp`. И если изменить режим округления с "по-умолчанию" на "в сторону +бесконечности" путём вставки в код чего-то вроде `_controlfp(_RC_UP, _MCW_RC);`, то `-1e+50` преобразуется не в `-Inf`, а в `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()`.

Comment: Хм, а ещё, начиная с C++11, для получения и установки режимов округления есть такие функции как `std::fegetround` и  `std::fesetround`.

Comment: @wololo, все эти функции имеют кучу сносок на то когда они действуют и как. Не вижу смысла их приводить, т.к. как они в точности работают я не знаю. Про операции с плавающей точкой и всё, что вокруг них крутится можно книгу написать.

Comment: @ixSci, Я просто хотел добавить, что значение не представимое в `float` не обязательно преобразуется в бесконечность. Этим аспектом преобразования можно управлять. (А иногда управление может происходить и без ведома программиста). Возможно, это пригодится кому-нибудь другому, кто будет интересоваться этим вопросом. Я, например, на момент задания вопроса, об этом не знал. Ну и Вы безусловно правы, что "все эти функции имеют кучу сносок на то когда они действуют и как".